# Faster way to pick up the blob at a given point

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to create an equivalent function for matlab's `bwselect`. So, I want to display the blob (which contains the points I will provide) and mask the rest. 
Here's what I have tried.

```
cv::Mat bwselect(cv::Mat matImg, int x, int y)
{
    cv::Mat img_labels, stats, centroids, mask;
    if (matImg.data)
    {
        int numOfLables = connectedComponentsWithStats(matImg, img_labels, stats, centroids, 8, CV_32S);

        if (numOfLables > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < numOfLables; i++)
            {
                mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img_labels.size(), CV_8UC1);
                mask = mask | (img_labels == i);
                if (mask.at<uchar>(y, x) > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return mask;
}
```

It does the job. But it's slow. Is there any faster and efficient way to do this?

Comment: That question is so open-ended that it's hard to answer. One thing that strikes me is the fact that there are paths that don't use certain variables, for example. In any case, you need to profile this in order to make it faster and perhaps use a different algorithm.

Comment: Why are you iterating for all the label numbers, try just to access it before the for, if it is 0 then it is backgrounds, else, is the number of the label, and then you can do the mask. Also, the matlab function uses watershed, you should try that one, it is also implemented in OpenCV and probably will be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input image is large and if it contains many objects, then the bottleneck could arise because you are allocating/deallocating a large mask buffer a lot of times.

Furthermore, if you call this function lots of times, it would be wise to call `connectedComponentsWithStats` only once and then use its results as additional input for your function.

I would suggest that you replace this entire loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < numOfLabels; i++){/*...*/}
```

with this

```
 // img_labels data type is CV_32S
 int label_at_pos = img_labels.at<int>(y, x); 

 if (label_at_pos > 0)
 {
    // create mask here and return it
 }
```

EDIT: I made a correction to my code sample above. The connectedComponentsWithStats computes labels image that contains integer values by default.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know how to access the label number directly with the coordinates. Thank you very much.